# I meet questions which "Works on my machine". Should I post an answer?

Tags: discussion, support, answers

I meet these questions frequently. They describe syntax error (example) which does not happen and CAN'T happen on given code. ([status-norepro](/questions/tagged/status-norepro))

Should I answer that everything is allright and problem is in another snippet of the code?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No, I'd **comment**, along the lines of:

> I couldn't reproduce your *[syntax error]*. Maybe you can post *[a more complete example]*, your problem might be a different one.

Because, if there's nothing to fix in the current question (e.g. a code example given), how are you ever going to correctly answer this? Wait until you get to the real problem, and then solve it with a real answer.

Comment: I did this once already, and OP just said "it works now". But, thanks for response!

Comment: Well, then the OP found a Heisenbug :) – seriously though, if they said "it works now", without posting their own solution, and without any details about *why* it does, the question should be deleted, because it's not going to be useful for anybody.

Comment: I hate Heisenbug  :p

Answer (score 3):

In those cases, I just leave a comment saying it works.

If I am in a good mood, I'll also post a link to show the code works (eg: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), [ideone](http://ideone.com/), [codepad](http://codepad.org/), [viper7](http://codepad.viper-7.com/) for php)

No better way to tell the OP their code works than showing that it works.

Answer (score 0):

Voting to close as 'not a real question' is appropriate if the context and tone of the question leaves you confident that either (a) they haven't, in fact, posted the code that they are getting the error on or (b) they have some bizarre and personal environment at fault. The latter might be 'too localized'.